# Hide/Unhide Imageview of children in a group on child click Expandablelistview

Tags: android, hide, android-imageview, expandablelistview, children

I am trying to implement a scenario in which user will select one option among many in a group.  See picture below:

[image]

Problem is that, when I click on a child, it does not hide/unhide the checkmark image of the clicked child.

My code is as follows:

**childLayout.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"  >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/childname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="medium Text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/checkmark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/checkmark" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childname"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkmark"
    android:src="@drawable/splitthehalfbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**On childclick listener**

```java
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    CreatePizzaAdapter adapter = (CreatePizzaAdapter) parent.getExpandableListAdapter();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getChildernCount().get(groupPosition); i++) {

        ImageView checkbox = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);

        if(i == childPosition)//toggle hidden
        {
            if(checkbox.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                    checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else//keep others hidden
        {
            checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong... Plz help me.. Thanks. If you need any additional code, just tell me.

Comment: Why do you need to loop through items. Doesn't `v` already have the row that was tapped?

Comment: Perhaps I now understand what you are trying to do. Let me know if this is correct. If an expanded item that is not checked is tapped, you want to check that item and uncheck all others in the group.

Comment: @JimRhodes yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{
  int iCount;
  int iIdx;
  Object item;

  CreatePizzaAdapter adapter = (CreatePizzaAdapter) parent.getExpandableListAdapter();

  iCount = adapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
  for ( iIdx = 0; iIdx < iCount; ++iIdx )
  {
    item = adapter.getChild(groupPosition, iIdx);
    if ( item != null )
    {
      // Here you would cast item to the appropriate type for this row

      if ( iIdx == childPosition )
      {
        // Here you would toggle checked state in the data for this item
      }
      else
      {
        // Here you would clear checked state in the data for this item
      }
    }
  }
  parent.invalidateViews(); // Update the list view
}
```

Comment: this is only toggling state of image present in row tapped. I also need to keep hide checkbox image on other siblings of that row. Do u know how can I achieve this?

Comment: @anum90 `v` IS the row tapped. Your loop gets the check box for the same row on every iteration of the loop. So when `i` is not equal to `childPosition`, you are making it invisible.

Comment: Wow Bingo! I was so stupid, I was just looping on same view, that's why I couldn't change others state. Thank you very much for help :)